# Using d3 and .data() to enter text

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

This is very simple but it's not working for me.

See [this example](http://code.hazzens.com/d3tut/lesson_1.html) where it *used* to work..

I've created a div, like this (the #stats_data div is already existent):

```
d3.select('#stats_data')
        .append('div')
        .attr('id', 'stats_data5')
        .text("626")
```

It's now in the DOM.

Now I would like to change that text based inside a D3.json function. The code is so simple but it's not working at all. I know you can change text with d3.select but the data-bound function is not operation.

```
d3.json("data/statsdata.json", function(statsData){
    d3.select('#stats_data5')
    .data(statsData)
    .text( function(d){
            console.log('test');
        return d.year2012;
    });
```

We get nothing, not a console.log or anything..

What's the best approach?

Comment: It just looks like you're defining the function, not calling it.

Comment: @Gerrat No, the function's being called. (the function housing d3.json, that is)

Comment: I was referring to the function that you're trying to do the logging in (the inner function).

Comment: Sorry, you're probably correct.

Comment: You are creating an element with ID `stats_data5`, but are trying to select an element with ID `stats_data`.

Comment: OK, how exactly does the first snippet add the element to the document? Because by itself, it doesn't (http://jsfiddle.net/AVBLa/).

Comment: @FelixKling It does indeed.. Maybe just not in a fiddle? Give it a shot in your browser.

Comment: See @FelixKling this: http://code.hazzens.com/d3tut/lesson_1.html it used to work..

Comment: Did you create element with id ="stats_data"?

Comment: @Tom All the elements are there.

Comment: d3.select('#stats_data')
        .append('div')
        .attr('id', 'stats_data5')
        .text("626")

the code here is to append a div with id='stats_data5' into a div with id='stats_data', you should add a <div id='stats_data'></div>

Comment: @Tom As I said the div is already there.

Comment: if so, please edit your jsfiddle more clearly, for the people can help you

Comment: @FelixKling The fiddle will work if you add <div id="stats_data"> In my code, the element is already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first snippet is doing the right thing, selecting an element on the DOM to be modified, but I would rewrite it as a variable (and remove the 626 text). So something like:

```
var aDiv = d3.select('body')
    .append('div')
    .attr('id', 'stats_data5');
```

Then when you select it again all you need to do is refer to aDiv.  In the next part you need to bind the data to the *new* elements you are creating with d3. So you need to use `enter()`.  You also have to tell d3 what to create or `append`.  So something like:

```
aDiv.selectAll("p")  //select all the empty p 
    .data(data)      // grab the data
    .enter()         // bind it to those previously empty p
  .append("p")       // add the p's t the DOM 
    .text( function(d){ // and you know what this does
        return d;
    });
```

You can see this all in [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bLfz9/)

Comment: Thanks. This is nice. The design pattern is better, indeed, with the variable assignment. I wish I didn't need to append the <p> though.. Any workaround ideas? That's what's nice about .text(). It seems the method changed, though.

Comment: you can use any element you want, append a span, a div or a heading.  I *think* you can event append just text.  You can class them and set the styles as well.  I was just looking at [Ian Johnson's presentation](http://enjalot.github.io/intro-d3/html5devconf/binding/) that goes over some of this and I'd also recommend [Scott Murray's book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026938.do) for getting started with d3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your call to `data/statsdata.json` is returning an object (and not an array of objects):

```
var statsData5 = d3.select('#stats_data5');
d3.json("data/statsdata.json", function(statsData) {
  statsData5.text(statsData.year2012);
});
```